# Postgresql JSON column check value exists in array of json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a database schema like the following where I have a Children record table

```
CREATE TABLE Children (
  name varchar(100),
  friends JSON NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO Children (name,friends)
VALUES('Sam',
        array['{"name":"Rakesh","country":"Africa"}', 
         '{"name":"Ramesh","country":"India"}']::json[]);
```

Now I need to query the data and display it only if the name of the friend is like '%Ra'. Structure of the JSON data is consistent.

Comment: The cast to `json[]` makes no sense to me - and it will result in the error "*column "friends" is of type json but expression is of type json[]*"

Answer (score 0):

If you have `json[]` as data type then you can use `unnest` and then write your query, or if it is `json` then you can use `json_array_elements`.

Below code considers `json[]` data type -

```
select * from Children
where name in (
select name from (
select name, unnest(friends) as friend from Children
  ) i
where i.friend->>'name' like '%Ra');
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbaQ2zmdsifXdJPCrPcZZs/0)

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbaQ2zmdsifXdJPCrPcZZs/1 (second query)